# Why does importing pyiwn result in an ImportError for the util module?

Tags: python, pip, wordnet

```
pip install pyiwn
Requirement already satisfied: pyiwn in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.9)
```

The details of the package are at https://pypi.org/project/pyiwn/ and https://github.com/riteshpanjwani/pyiwn

```
>>> from pyiwn import pyiwn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/#USER_NAME/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyiwn/pyiwn.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyiwn import utils
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

can anyone solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can force a **pip re-install**, without using the cached version.

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyiwn --no-cache-dir`

or for py2.7, pip1.4+ use `--no-deps --ignore-installed`

Comment: Tried the above pip re-install command for py2.7. The same error keeps repeating

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the error occurred as the developer didn't mention which python to use. My pip install defaulted to python2. But the pyiwn library only works for python3. That's the reason for utils error.